# Python code on Windows has some problems on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x

I developed a python code that converts HTML to PDF.
For this, I convert HTML to Image and convert Image to PDF again.
My code works well on my platform(windows) but does not work on MacOS.

```
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from PIL import Image
import img2pdf
import os
import sys

arguments=sys.argv
FileUrl=arguments[1]
for path, currentDirectory, files in os.walk(FileUrl):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            driver=webdriver.Chrome()
            filepath=os.path.join(path, file)
            imageoutputPath=filepath.replace('.html','_desktop.png')
            pdfoutputPath=filepath.replace('.html','_desktop.pdf')
            driver.get(filepath)
            time.sleep(3)
            height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight )")
            print(height)
            driver.close()
            chrome_options = Options()
            chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
            chrome_options.add_argument(f"--window-size=700,{height}")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
            driver.get(filepath)
            driver.save_screenshot(imageoutputPath)
            image = Image.open(imageoutputPath)
            pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image.filename)
            file = open(pdfoutputPath, "wb")
            file.write(pdf_bytes)
            image.close()
            file.close()
            print("Successfully made pdf file")
            os.remove(imageoutputPath)
            driver.close()
```

The 26 th line
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--window-size=700,{height}")
has syntax invalid error

Please let me know how to fix this problem

Comment: And it works on Windows?

Comment: I cant suggest an edit RN. Please add a chrome and a OSX tag to it

Comment: Which python version are you running on each of your devices?

Comment: yes, it works on windows correctly.

Comment: python3 is used.

Comment: my guess is the Python version on the Mac does not have f-strings. f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run this code on my local. On windows, it works perfect.
In Mac,

1. you can change 26th line like below first.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=700,"+f{height}")
```

2. driver=webdriver.Chrome() might not work, I think.
   I recommend use chromedriver like this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

You can also use chromedriver like this. But I know, executable_path was deprecated.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

I am sure you installed all modules using pip3 install.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: So far so good. But imageoutputPath, pdfoutputPath can't be read.

Comment: maybe you entered fileUrl as an absolute url? Try with this way. You can use fileUrl as an absolute url. But for imageoutputPath, try with only filename.